# implementation of ngShow

Tags: angularjs, directive, ng-show

Had this working earlier, now it doesnt respond accordingly.

In my html:

`<div ng-click="setFalse();" ng-show"emptyspotslist">No results</div>`

Controller:

```
$scope.setFalse = function () {
$scope.emptyspotslist = !$scope.emptyspotslist;
console.log($scope.emptyspotslist);
}
```

Default value of $scope.emptyspotslist = true.
The DIV doesnt hide, after clicking. Function gets called though.
Probably something really simple i'm overlooking.

Comment: Put an = between the ng-show and "emptyspotslist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `=` after `ng-show` attribute

Old

```
<div ng-click="setFalse();" ng-show"emptyspotslist">No results</div>
```

New

```
<div ng-click="setFalse();" ng-show="emptyspotslist">No results</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is malformed...

```
ng-show="emptyspotslist"
```

You're missing an equals `=`.

Comment: Well thats embarrassing. New to Angular but not new to writing html, tags and attributes..